# Matching Patterns for list of tuples

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

I'm trying to write a fcn that takes in a list of tuple and an expression (I am working on a postfix expression eval). This function should loop through the expression and find the same letter in the tuple. If it's a match then it returns the int value corresponding to that letter in the tuple. When I ran the code below, my program compiled and run but then it was hanging during execution. What did I do wrong?

```
    let rec getVar ls exp = 

        match ls with
       |head::tl when (fst head) = exp -> printfn "%d" (snd head)
       | _  -> getVar ls exp



    let ls = [("a",5);("b",2);("c",3)]

    let exp = "ab+"
    getVar ls exp
```

Comment: Please don't edit your question in such a way that existing answers stop making sense. And if you have another question, ask another question, don't reuse an old one.

Answer (score 3):

Your `match` expression has a final catch-all clause (the `_` clause) that just calls `getVar` again with the same parameters. If the `when (fst head) = exp` condition fails, then code falls through to the catch-all clause, so `getVar` gets called again with the same parameters, so the first condition will fail, so code falls through to the catch-all clause, so `getVar` gets called again... It's an infinite loop.

What you probably meant to do was call `getVar` again on the *tail* of the list if your `when` condition failed:

```
match ls with
|head::tail when (fst head) = exp -> printfn "%d" (snd head)
|head::tail -> getVar tail exp
```

You also need to think about what you'll do if the list is empty (i.e., you need a match condition that matches against `[]`). I'll leave that one up to you, since there are many things you *could* want to do with an empty list and it's not obvious which one you'd want.

Comment: I did change as suggested, and I also added a match condition for an empty list case as well. Still the program hangs when I executed. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @LongPham Could you add your new version as an edit to your original question? rmunns version (without adding the [] case) should give a runtime error unless the list contains exp. With a sensible [] case it should work just fine.

Comment: @Guran Just added a new edited version! Like I stated before. I compiled this code just fine. When I ran it, the program hangs and no value is printed out

Comment: @LongPham Thanks, but you should have kept the old version as well, since this edit makes rmunns very valid answer suddenly invalid.

Comment: @LongPham - I saw your edit where you included a `[]` match, and you have the same problem: your `[]` match just calls the function again without any change in parameters, so if the code ever falls through to the `[]` case, it will enter an infinite loop. Your `[]` case should just return some value (even if it's just the `()` value that means "do nothing", which is probably what you want here).

Answer (score 2):

Your match must handle three cases.

1. Empty list -> return some default value (or unit without side effects)
2. Match found -> return a value or trigger some side effect.
3. Match not yet found -> keep searching in tail of list.

In your first attempt, you accidentally kept searching in the whole list instead of merely the tail, resulting in an endless recursive loop.
In your second attempt, you instead created an infinite loop in the empty case.
Below is one example of how you might write the recursive function.

```
 let rec getVar ls exp =
     match ls with
     |[] -> None
     |head::tail when (fst head) = exp -> Some <| sprintf "%d" (snd head)
     |head::tail  -> getVar tail exp

 let ls = [("a",5);("b",2);("c",3)]

 let result1 = getVar ls "ab+"   // result = None
 let result2 = getVar ls "b"     // result = Some "2"
```

Comment: thanks for pointing that out! However, for the exp "ab+" , the function should be returning 5 and 2 and ignore the operator. I don't get why your solution returns None

Comment: Well, you are matching for equality between fst head and exp. That is true iff the first part of the tuple is exactly exp. “AB+” in your case.

Comment: Oh I see. Maybe I should be comparing each character of exp instead of the entire string.

Comment: Yes, obviously this code is still a long way from a postfix calculator (which I assume is your goal). I just tried to fix the problem in your question without writing everything for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

The signature of your `getVar` function is wrong. The last parameter should be a letter of the expression, not the whole expression. The code  calling the `getVar` function would go through the expression, for each character, check if it is a letter, if yes then call `getVar`, otherwise then do other things.

The reason why you code gets hanged is explained clearly in the other answers so I won’t repeat here. But as a good practice, please don’t use `| _ -> ...` unless you totally control the situation. Typically, we should explicitly write all the matching conditions, so that if we miss something, compiler will warn us. After that, when being aware all the conditions, we can use `| _ -> ...` if it really means “the rest condition**s**”.

Your `getVar` function can be rewritten as:

```
let rec getVar ls letter =
    match ls with
    | [] -> ()
    | head :: tail when fst head = letter -> printfn "%d" (snd head)
    | _ :: tail -> getVar tail letter
```

I suggest you learn the common built-in functions of F# core library. So you can use the `List.tryFind` function in your problem:

```
let getVar ls letter =
    ls |> List.tryFind (fun (key, value) ->
                 if key = letter then
                     printfn "%d" value
                     true
                 else false)
```

The more you can use bult-in functions, the less bugs you have.